# How to delete a task in a todo list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, vuex, store

I'm expecting to delete an individual task in the array via DELETE request, but I'm having the **404** error, even though the url is correct and I'm passing the userId in the method, or should I use id instead. Meanwhile the url array has both - the userId and the id for each element.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-bootstrap-vue-dynamic-img-bkwixg?file=pages%2Findex.vue,store%2Findex.js,components%2FTask.vue

```js
// Child component

<template>
  <div :class="{ task: task.completed }">
    {{ task.todo }}
    <button @click="deleteTask" class="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  props: ['task'],
    deleteTask(userId) {
      this.$store.dispatch('deleteTask');
    },
  },
};
</script>

// Parent component

<template>
  <Task v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" :task="task" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      todo: '',
      completed: false,

    };
  },
  computed: {
    tasks() {
      return this.$store.state.tasks;
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getTasks').then((data) => console.log(this.tasks));
  },
  methods: {
  },
};
</script>

// Store 

export const state = () => ({
  tasks: [],
});

export const actions = {
  async getTasks(context) {
    const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/todos');
    if (res.ok) {
      let result = await res.json();
      context.commit('setTasks', result.todos);
    }
    return res.ok;
  },
  async deleteTask(context, id) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/todos/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
      },
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      let result = await res.json();
      context.dispatch('getTasks');
    }
    return res.ok;
  }
};

export const mutations = {
  setTasks(state, data) {
    state.tasks = data;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass id `@click="deleteTask(task.id)"` and in method:

```
deleteTask(id) {
  this.$store.dispatch('deleteTask', id);
},
```

Comment: Keeps the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving 404 because you a calling `https://dummyjson.com/todos/undefined`

1 - You need to dispatch the id:

```
  // Task.vue - line 26
  deleteTask(id) {
        this.$store.dispatch('deleteTask', id);
  },
```

2 - also, call the "deleteTask" method with the id:

```
  // Task.vue - line 10
  <button @click="() => deleteTask(task.id)" class="delete">Delete</button>
```

after that, you will call `https://dummyjson.com/todos/1`

Comment: it keeps the same error 404

Comment: I just opened the StackBlitz, line 26 is OK, but line 10 still needs to be fixed. Did you put both instructions? I changed the line 10, and I didn't get the 404.

Comment: Also, dummyjson will return status OK, but UI will not update because you are getting tasks again and "Deleting a todo will not delete it into the server".
source:https://dummyjson.com/docs/todos#delete

Comment: Now it does delete, thx, but it deletes now all of the new todo from the list by clicking the delete button